Toggle a session variable that subsets database
I'm relatively new to Rails, and so hope I word this correctly.
I have a database of coral species data. There are 1000s of species from two broad groups of corals: Hexacorals and Octocorals (coded in the species data table). When people use the database, they might want to work with (1) all species, (2) just Hexacoral species, or (3) just Octocoral species.
I was trying to subset the data using a params variable passed with the URL (?group=Hexacorals and params[:group]).  But I can't help thinking there's a more efficient way of doing this using an application or session variable. Ideally, I would like a toggle / radio button in the header for people to freely switch between these database states.
Any help truly appreciated.


But I can't help thinking there's a more efficient way of doing this using an application or session variable.

Not really.
What you're doing is actually the "correct" way if you want to maintain the idea of idempotency (that the same URI should look the same regardless of who's visiting the page). This is a pretty core tenant in REST.
If you instead move this filtering into the session it has a lot of negative effects:

Users cannot just share the URI and get the same results.
The session is cookie dependent. If the user declines cookies your site is now broken?
You cannot just use the URI together with E-Tags which is very efficient way of caching and serving the same response to different visitors. This can be done on the web server level while the session can only be decoded by your rails app.

There are valid use cases where you do want to store user specific setting or state in the session instead of as HTTP parameters but you need to weigh it against the cons.
Arguably you could also model this differently so you have the paths:
/corals
/groups/octocorals 
/groups/hexacorals

Instead of jamming everything into a single path with query string parameters.
If you want to have some sort of toggle it is still achievable with JavaScript but don't let that requirement lead you to questionable design choices.
